# Mysql query to replace a field based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have this in my database

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id        | notes                                                         |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         | {jsonmodel_type":"note", "content":[";;; A2 ;; Yer ;;;;;;;"]} |
| 2         | {jsonmodel_type":"note", "content":[";;; A3 ;; Hey ;;;;;;;"]} |            
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How would I write the sql query to remove any part of the notes column that contains more than two semi colons. For example, I would want my database to look like this after.

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id        | notes                                                         |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         | {jsonmodel_type":"note", "content":["A2 ;; Yer "]}            |
| 2         | {jsonmodel_type":"note", "content":["A3 ;; Hey "]}            |     
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

hii perhaps something like `update t set notes = regexp_replace(notes, ';{3,}', '')`